# Capturar um registro em uma table para depois inserir no banco

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário para cadastro de ordem de serviços para uma oficina. Preciso que o serviço cadastrado esteja vinculado a um cliente já cadastrado.

Para isso criei um formulário de busca onde o usuário pode buscar os clientes cadastrados e selecionar apenas um.

No form tenho:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Localize o Cliente</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cliente" id="cliente" placeholder="Informe o nome do cliente para fazer a busca">
        <span class="input-group-btn">                                                                                  
           <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="buscar">Buscar!</button>                                                                              
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="dados">aparece os dados aqui</div>
```

Como demonstrado na div id="dados", os dados são exibidos após uma consulta no BD. Para buscar os dados sem refresh no browser usei o AJAX.

```
function buscar(cliente) {
       var page = "busca_cliente.php";
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'html',
           url: page,
           beforeSend: function () {
               $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
           },
           data: {palavra: cliente},
           success: function (msg) {
               $("#dados").html(msg)
           }
       });
   }
   $("#buscar").click(function (){
       buscar($("#cliente").val())
   });
```

O arquivo que traz os dados é o buscar_cliente.php

```
// claro, antes existem as linhas de conexão e busca, estão funcionando e os dados estão na variável $query 
<table class="table" id="tabela">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <i>
                    Cliente
                </i>
            </th>
            <th>
                <i>
                    Telefone
                </i>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($query as $linha) {
        ?>
            <tr> 
                <td id="selecao"> <?php echo $linha->nome ?> </a></td>
                <td> <?php echo $linha->telefone . ' ou ' . $linha->celular ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "Cliente não encontrado";
```

Eu preciso permitir que o usuário selecione apenas uma valor nessa tabela, ao selecionar uma linha o valor é exibido em uma label, por exemplo o nome do cliente, e o id do cliente é armazenado em uma variável para depois eu fazer o insert na tabela de serviço.

Já busquei na net e não vi nada parecido, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira observação é criar um `id` único para a `td` no laço `foreach`. Coloque o `id` do cliente no lugar de `selecao`:

```
<tr> 
    <td id="<?=$id_cliente?>"> <?php echo $linha->nome ?> </a></td>
    <td> <?php echo $linha->telefone . ' ou ' . $linha->celular ?></td>
</tr>
```

Use o jQuery abaixo para capturar a `id` e jogar na variável `var id_cliente` e adicionar o nome do cliente na `<caption>` (esse `caption` eu coloquei apenas como exemplo, você criar outra coisa):

```
$(document).on("click","#tabela td a",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var id_cliente = $(this).parent().attr("id");
   $("#tabela caption").text($(this).text());
});
```

**Veja um exemplo funcionando:**

```js
$(document).on("click","#tabela td a",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var id_cliente = $(this).parent().attr("id");
   $("#tabela caption").text($(this).text());
   console.log(id_cliente); // apenas para verificar o valor
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tabela">
     <caption></caption>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
         <th>
             <i>
                 Cliente
             </i>
         </th>
         <th>
             <i>
                 Telefone
             </i>
         </th>
     </tr>
      <tr> 
          <td id="id1"> <a href="">Nome 1</a></td>
          <td> telefone</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
          <td id="id2"> <a href="">Nome 2</a></td>
          <td> telefone</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
          <td id="id3"> <a href="">Nome 3</a></td>
          <td> telefone</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

> Se você for usar a variável `id_cliente` em outra função, retire o
>   `var`:

```
$(document).on("click","#tabela td a",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   id_cliente = $(this).parent().attr("id");
   $("#tabela caption").text($(this).text());
   console.log(id_cliente); // apenas para verificar o valor
});
```

Comment: Cara, a ideia é essa mesmo, só que no exemplo que você me passou os dados estão estáticos e num único arquivo.
No meu caso eu tenho o arquivo com o formulário para a busca. Coloquei o caption que me sugeriu nesse arquivo pois é onde eu desejo que seja exibido o nome do cliente.
Tenho um outro arquivo que faz a busca no banco de dados e exibe os dados em uma tabela e essa tabela é chamada no formulário através de uma função javascript.
Acontece que ao clicar no link na tabela está dando um refresh na página chamando perdendo os dados. Se preciso te mando os arquivos completos.

Comment: perfeito, é isso mesmo... 
Agora preciso colocar o texto do link em um input(id='valor') no formulário. Seria assim? 
$(document).getElementById('valor').text($(this).text());
Não deu certo

Comment: Lógico né, o getElementById não pode ser... :-|

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71369/discussion-between-rafael-christofano-and-dvd).